# fatal: unable to access 'direction': Could not resolve host: name_user

Tags: git, github

Me manda ese error la terminal de git bash cuando intento subir un repositorio a Github con este comando:

```
git push -u origin main
```

Y ya probe:

```
git config --global http.proxy
```

Tampoco me ha funcionado puesto junto:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push -u origin main
```

Me aparece lo siguiente:

```
20:13:24.860558 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
20:13:24.865559 git.c:458               trace: built-in: git push origin main
20:13:24.868596 run-command.c:654       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https origin https://Danielbn64/php-fullstack.git
20:13:24.886527 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
20:13:24.888564 git.c:746               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://Danielbn64/php-fullstack.git
20:13:24.888564 run-command.c:654       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://Danielbn64/php-fullstack.git
20:13:24.907564 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
fatal: unable to access 'https://Danielbn64/php-fullstack.git/': Could not resolve host: Danielbn64
```

Comment: Yo supongo que bien no tienes bien configurado el proxy _o_ no tienes bien configurado el remoto al que estás haciendo push. Verifica ambas direcciones.

Comment: Hola mi url está bien pero no sé qué se refiere el con el proxy ni como configurarlo, yo ya he subido repositorios a github antes y no habia tenido tenido ese problema.

Comment: Haz una corrida del comando de push pero así: `GIT_TRACE=1 git push blahblahblah` y colocas la salida en la pregunta.

Comment: Tendrías que hacer la asignación de la variable y el comando git en una sola línea (como lo puse en mi instrucción) o hacer un export de la variable y entonces llamar a git: `export GIT_TRACE=1; git push blahblah`

Comment: Revisa bien tu configuración local para el repositorio, la global y la dirección del remoto al que estás haciendo push